# Calling Firebase.instance.verifyPhoneNumber() is causing flutter app(android) to crash

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to add phone Authentication to my app, but it is causing my app to crash. (I'm using for android only right now.)

Here's the code :

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:groci/Shared/Constants.dart';

class AuthServices {

  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  final TextEditingController _verController = TextEditingController();

  Future registerWithPhone(BuildContext context, String phoneNo) async {
    print("it's working till here : $phoneNo");
    try {
      await _auth.verifyPhoneNumber(phoneNumber: phoneNo,
          verificationCompleted: (AuthCredential authCredential) {
            print("Verification Complete");
          },

          verificationFailed: (FirebaseAuthException exception) {
            print(exception.toString());
          },

          codeSent: (String verCode, int rewind) {
            print("Code sent");
            showDialog(context: context, builder: (_) {
              return AlertDialog(
                title: Text("Enter the verification code"),
                actions: <Widget>[
                  TextField(
                    controller: _verController,
                    decoration: formFieldDecoration.copyWith(
                        hintText: "VerCode"),
                  ),
                  FlatButton(
                    child: Text("Enter"),
                    onPressed: () {
                      print("working");
                    },
                  )
                ],
              );
            });
          },

          codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: (String code) {
            print("didn't work");
          });

    }catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
    }
  }
}
```

And here's a part of console:

```
I/flutter (10581): it's working till here.
E/zza     (10581): Problem retrieving SafetyNet Token: 7: 
I/zzip    (10581): Provider GmsCore_OpenSSL not available
D/AndroidRuntime(10581): Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime(10581): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(10581): Process: com.example.groci, PID: 10581
E/AndroidRuntime(10581): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroidx/browser/customtabs/CustomTabsIntent$Builder;
E/AndroidRuntime(10581):    at com.google.firebase.auth.internal.RecaptchaActivity.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@20.0.0:92)
E/AndroidRuntime(10581):    at com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzeq.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@20.0.0:79)
E/AndroidRuntime(10581):    at com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzeq.onPostExecute(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@20.0.0:88)
```

I couldn't find much help to this online. I have sha-1 key setup in firebase console with phone authentication enable too.

Comment: Did what Ayush said, and implemented androidx. That made it work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was facing the exact same issue.

I am guessing you have not enabled the Device Check API. For some reason it was crashing because of that. All you need to do is enable the Device Check API on the cloud platform.

I think after some updates they have made this change that for Safety Net you need SH1 Authentication along with enabling Device Check API.

You can follow the Steps as mentioned [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/phone-auth).

Do lemme know if you need further steps.